# sed search and replace between string and last occurence of character

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I currently have a bunch of .md5sum files with a md5sum hash value and it's corresponding file name with full absolute path. I'd like to modify these files from being absolute pathing to relative. I think I have it pretty close.

```
> cat example.md5sum
197f76c53d2918764cfa6463b7221dec  /example/path/to/file/example.null
> cat example.md5sum | sed 's/(  ).*\//  \.\//'
197f76c53d2918764cfa6463b7221dec  /example/path/to/file/example.null
```

Throwing the regex `(  ).*\/` into notepad++ returns `/example/path/to/file/` which is what I want. Moving it over to `sed` does not produce the same match.

The end goal here as mentioned previously is the following:

```
197f76c53d2918764cfa6463b7221dec  ./example.null
```

Comment: Must this be done in tcsh, or would you be open to a POSIX shell solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a job for sed.

```
sed -i.bak 's:/.*/:./:' file ...
```

The `-i` option tells sed to modify files "in-place" rather than sending the results to stdout. With the `s`ubstitute command, you can use alternate delimiters -- in this case, I've used a colon, since the text you're matching and using as replacement includes slashes. Makes things easier to read.

I haven't bothered to match the whitespace before the path, because in an md5sum file has a pretty predictable format.

Back up your input files before experimenting.

Note that this is shell agnostic -- you can run it in tcsh or bash or anything else that is able to launch sed with options.

Comment: Thanks ghoti. Final solution:

`find . -type f -name "*.md5sum" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i.bak 's:/.*/:./:'`

Comment: @DuckCowMooQuack - also consider using find's `-exec` option, which would eliminate the need to pipe through xargs. For example: `find /path -type f -name \*.md5sum -exec sed -i.bak 's:/.*/:./:' {} +`

Comment: @ghoti How does `-exec` handle spaces in filenames?

Comment: The filenames that `{}` gets translated to are implicitly quoted by find, so things work just fine. Filenames with newlines are also perfectly fine.